# Dataset size is smaller than memory, What's wrong with my code?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, training-data, dataloader

The following is part of the code, epoch=300, each npz file is 2.73M, but the batch size of my dataloader gives 64, a total of 8 gpuss, so a mini batch should be 64×8×2.73M≈1.1G, my actual memory is 128G. Even if it becomes larger after decompression, it will not reach the size of 128G. The following figure link shows that all 128G of memory is occupied. How should I change my code?

```
class VimeoDataset(Dataset):
def __init__(self, dataset_name, batch_size=64):
    def __init__(self, dataset_name, batch_size=32):
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.path = '/data/train_sample/dataset/'
    self.dataset_name = dataset_name
    #self.load_data()
    self.h = 256
    self.w = 448
    xx = np.arange(0, self.w).reshape(1,-1).repeat(self.h,0) #xx shape is(256,448)
    yy = np.arange(0, self.h).reshape(-1,1).repeat(self.w,1) #yy shape is(448,256)
    self.grid = np.stack((xx,yy),2).copy()

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.meta_data)

def getimg(self, index):
    f = np.load('/data/train_sample/dataset/'+ str(index) + '.npz')
    if index < 8000:
        train_data = f['i0i1gt']
        flow_data = f['ft0ft1'] 
    elif 8000 <= index < 10000:
        val_data = f['i0i1gt']
    else:
        pass

    if self.dataset_name == 'train':
        meta_data = train_data
    else:
        meta_data = val_data

    data = meta_data
    img0 = data[0:3].transpose(1, 2, 0)
    img1 = data[3:6].transpose(1, 2, 0)
    gt = data[6:9].transpose(1, 2, 0)
    flow_gt = flow_data.transpose(1, 2, 0)
    return img0, gt, img1, flow_gt  

    dataset = VimeoDataset('train')
def __getitem__(self, index):        
    img0, gt, img1, flow_gt = self.getimg(index)
    ...

sampler = DistributedSampler(dataset) 
train_data = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=args.batch_size, num_workers=8, pin_memory=True, 
drop_last=True, sampler=sampler)
```

[system usage figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EMrm.png)

Comment: You're loading all of your data into memory at once by loading the variables self.train_data/val_data. The point of a dataset is the __getitem__ which will extract a SINGLE item to avoid this memory overload. This is the method called by the dataloader too, which will be run in the background of your model training on the CPU to minimise memory overhead.

Comment: I have changed my code just now. You can have a look. But there are still some errors, and I don't know why it's wrong with UnboundLocalError: local variable 'val_data' referenced before assignment and some other errors.

Comment: Your getimg function has two methods of sorting into train/validation. I think the first one (where you compare the index against 8000) is unnecessary. You need to make your datasets for train/validation data come from the same class so that you can call the same function with different parameters and receive two similar objects representing different data.

Comment: hi jhso, Can you help me solve this similar problem，https://stackoverflow.com/q/67076489/15492797?stw=2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have given fixing your dataset given our comments above a go. Essentially you need to pass more variables into your class so that it can easily differentiate between your train and validation data. This is without loading all of your data into memory, although sometimes this is necessary (sequentially, not at once) to calculate some data statistics and such.

Disclaimer: I took a guess at using glob to find your npz files and that you use flow_data in your validation set (missing in your code for validation data).

```
from glob import glob
class VimeoDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, npzs, batch_size=64,train_set=False):
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.train_set = train_set
        self.h = 256
        self.w = 448
        xx = np.arange(0, self.w).reshape(1,-1).repeat(self.h,0) #xx shape is(256,448)
        yy = np.arange(0, self.h).reshape(-1,1).repeat(self.w,1) #yy shape is(448,256)
        self.grid = np.stack((xx,yy),2).copy()
        self.npzs = npzs        

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.npzs)
    
    def getimg(self, index):
        f = np.load(self.npzs[index])
        data = f['i0i1gt']
        if self.train_set:
            flow_data = f['ft0ft1']
        else: 
            flow_data = np.zeros([self.h,self.w,4]) 
        img0 = data[0:3].transpose(1, 2, 0)
        img1 = data[3:6].transpose(1, 2, 0)
        gt = data[6:9].transpose(1, 2, 0)
        flow_gt = flow_data.transpose(1, 2, 0)
        return img0, gt, img1, flow_gt  
    
    def __getitem__(self, index):        
        img0, gt, img1, flow_gt = self.getimg(index)

npzs = glob('/data/train_sample/dataset/*.npz')
train_val_split = 8000
train_dataset = VimeoDataset(npzs[:train_val_split],train_set = True)
val_dataset = VimeoDataset(npzs[train_val_split:])
```

Comment: I still have two questions. First, my dataset folder has only 10,000 npz files, and no train_sample and val_sample folders are designed, so I hope that the first 8,000 will be used for training and the rest will be used for verification. Second, in val_dataset, I only need data, which is f['i0i1gt'], and flow_data f['ft0ft1'] in val_dataset should be set np.zeros((256, 448, 4)). So can you modify the code again. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Edited, as you can see it's possible to pass the file names in as arguments if you want to split it this way. I also just created a new input which tells the model if it's the train set or not.

Comment: Hi, jhso. I have implemented your code, and it has run successfully. However, since the data is loaded from the HDD one by one, the data loading process takes a long time. So how to improve the program, to load the required batch-size data into the memory first, instead of just loading one or all of the data.